# How to get objects by State in REST API

Tags: django, angular, rest, django-rest-framework, single-page-application

I am working on an SPA angular/django, I have designed `action` ressources to be retrieved by Id (this way I can better handle cache in front). However, front needs for some features to **retrieve actions by state** instead of id :

**Option 1**

- Create new root `api/actions/:state`

**Option 2**

- Return list of action ids by state in `GET: api/projects/:id` route.
- fetch state related ids using existing root `api/actions/:id`

Whis option would be cleaner ?

Comment: What about adding a query param to `/api/actions/`? So ir would be: `/api/actions/?state=whatever`?

Comment: Did you try 'lookup_field' attribute in ModelViewset?

Comment: @origamic it's not technical problem related to django, I am asking in general about best practices of designing REST APIs for SPAs

Comment: @Opal That has the same cons as the first option I have mentioned above. If i have 2000 urgent actions in cache and api/actions/urgent returns 2001 objects. This way I would call the back just to have one more action